# PHP problem import excel into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, excel, xlsx

I wan't to import a xlsx file into my mysql database. For it I use the library nuovo spreadsheet reader:
https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader/
I can import into my database the simple xlsx file in this site:
https://phppot.com/php/import-excel-file-into-mysql-database-using-php/

But when I MODIFY the file for import a player, the upload is done but there are nothing in the database. I don't understand why.

The code for read and inject the data in the database:

```
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Service\FileUploader;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use SpreadsheetReader_XLSX;


/**
 * @Route("/file")
 */
class UploadController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/upload", name="upload_player")
 */
public function indexUpload()
{
    return $this->render('upload/form.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'UploadController',
    ]);
}

    /**
     * @Route("/doUpload", name="doUpload")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, string $uploadDir, FileUploader $uploader, LoggerInterface $logger)
    {
        $token = $request->get("token");

        if (!$this->isCsrfTokenValid('upload', $token)) 
        {
            $logger->info("CSRF failure");

            return new Response("Operation not allowed",  Response::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST,
                ['content-type' => 'text/plain']);
        }        

        $file = $request->files->get('myfile');

        if (empty($file)) 
        {
            return new Response("No file specified",  
               Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, ['content-type' => 'text/plain']);
        }        

        $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploader->upload($uploadDir, $file, $filename);



        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","db_password","db_name");

        $targetPath = '../var/uploads/'.$filename;
            $Reader = new SpreadsheetReader_XLSX($targetPath);

            $sheetCount = count($Reader->sheets());
            for($i=0;$i<$sheetCount;$i++)
            {

                $Reader->ChangeSheet($i);

                foreach ($Reader as $Row)
                {

                    $lastname = "";
                    if(isset($Row[0])) {
                        $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[0]);
                    }

                    $firstname = "";
                    if(isset($Row[1])) {
                        $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[1]);
                    }

                    $picture = "";
                    if(isset($Row[2])) {
                        $picture = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[2]);
                    }

                    $birthday = "";
                    if(isset($Row[3])) {
                        $birthday = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[3]);
                    }

                    $nationality = "";
                    if(isset($Row[4])) {
                        $nationality = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[4]);
                    }

                    $address = "";
                    if(isset($Row[5])) {
                        $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[5]);
                    }

                    $postal = "";
                    if(isset($Row[6])) {
                        $postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[6]);
                    }

                    $city = "";
                    if(isset($Row[7])) {
                        $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[7]);
                    }

                    $Email = "";
                    if(isset($Row[8])) {
                        $Email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[8]);
                    }

                    $jerseyNumber = "";
                    if(isset($Row[9])) {
                        $jerseyNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[9]);
                    }

                    $footShoot = "";
                    if(isset($Row[10])) {
                        $footShoot = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[10]);
                    }

                    $shoeSize = "";
                    if(isset($Row[11])) {
                        $shoeSize = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[11]);
                    }

                    $jerseySize = "";
                    if(isset($Row[12])) {
                        $jerseySize = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[12]);
                    }

                    $shortSize = "";
                    if(isset($Row[13])) {
                        $shortSize = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[13]);
                    }

                    $licenceNumber = "";
                    if(isset($Row[14])) {
                        $licenceNumber = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[14]);
                    }

                    $mobilePhone = "";
                    if(isset($Row[15])) {
                        $mobilePhone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[15]);
                    }

                    $fixPhone = "";
                    if(isset($Row[16])) {
                        $fixPhone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[16]);
                    }

                    $note = "";
                    if(isset($Row[17])) {
                        $note = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[17]);
                    }

                    $team = "";
                    if(isset($Row[19])) {
                        $team = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[19]);
                    }

                    $categories = "";
                    if(isset($Row[20])) {
                        $categories = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$Row[20]);
                    }

                    if (!empty($lastname) || !empty($firstname)) {

                        $query = "insert into player(lastname,firstname, picture, birthday, nationality, address, postal, city, Email, jerseyNumber, footShoot, shoeSize, jerseySize, shortSize, licenceNumber, mobilePhone, fixPhone, note, team, categories) values('".$lastname."','".$firstname."','".$picture."','".$birthday."','".$nationality."','".$nationality."','".$address."','".$postal."','".$city."','".$Email."','".$jerseyNumber."','".$footShoot."','".$shoeSize."','".$jerseySize."','".$shortSize."','".$licenceNumber."','".$mobilePhone."','".$fixPhone."','".$note."','".$team."','".$categories."')";

                        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

                        if (! empty($result)) {
                            $type = "success";
                            $message = "Excel Data Imported into the Database";
                        } else {
                            $type = "error";
                            $message = "Problem in Importing Excel Data";
                        }
                    }
                 }

                }


        return new Response("File uploaded",  Response::HTTP_OK, ['content-type' => 'text/plain']);         

            }
        }
```

I have the response "file uploaded" but not the data in my database.

Comment: What do you mean by "not the data in my database"? Is the row missing or are values in it blank? On side notes: 1) you're wide open to [SQL injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work) and 2) you really shouldn't be executing all that logic in the controller, you should create services to do the work and then just call them in your controller actions.

Comment: With a xlsx file, i have this error: XMLReader::open(): Empty string supplied as input. With a xls file, i have this error : iconv(): Detected an incomplete multibyte character in input string. First, I wan't make it working, and then I will see to ameliorate my code.

Answer (score 0):

finally I changed the library because I can't use numbers. I changed to PHPOFFICE. Now everything is working. My code is not the best and is only for dev but it works:

````
namespace App\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use App\Service\FileUploader;
use Exception;


/**
 * @Route("/file")
 */
class UploadController extends AbstractController
{
/**
 * @Route("/upload", name="upload_player")
 */
public function indexUpload()
{
    return $this->render('upload/form.html.twig', [
        'controller_name' => 'UploadController',
    ]);
}

    /**
     * @Route("/doUpload", name="doUpload")
     */
    public function index(Request $request, string $uploadDir, FileUploader $uploader)
    {


        $file = $request->files->get('myfile');

        if (empty($file)) 
        {
            return new Response("No file specified",  
               Response::HTTP_UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY, ['content-type' => 'text/plain']);
        }        

        $inputFileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
        $uploader->upload($uploadDir, $file, $inputFileName);

        $targetPath = '../var/uploads/'.$inputFileName;



        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","db_user","db_password","db_name");



        /**  Identify the type of $inputFileName  **/
        $inputFileType = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::identify($targetPath);

        /**  Create a new Reader of the type that has been identified  **/
        $reader = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);

        /**  Load $inputFileName to a Spreadsheet Object  **/
        $spreadsheet = $reader->load($targetPath);

        $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();

        $highestRow = $worksheet->getHighestRow(); // total number of rows

        $highestColumn = $worksheet->getHighestColumn(); // total number of columns

        $highestColumnIndex = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell\Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($highestColumn); // e.g. 5



        if ($highestRow <= 0) {
            Exit ('There is no data in the Excel table');
        }


        for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {

            $lastname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(1, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $firstname = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(2, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $picture = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(3, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $birthday = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(4, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $nationality = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(5, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(6, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(7, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(8, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(9, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $jersey_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(10, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $foot_shoot = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(11, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $shoe_size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(12, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $jersey_size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(13, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $short_size = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(14, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $licence_number = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(15, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $mobile_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(16, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $fix_phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(17, $row)->getFormattedValue());
            $note = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(18, $row)->getFormattedValue());

/*with foreign key:*/
            $team = ("SELECT id FROM team WHERE name = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(19, $row)->getFormattedValue())."'"); 
            $category = ("SELECT id FROM categories WHERE type = '". mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $worksheet->getCellByColumnAndRow(20, $row)->getFormattedValue())."'"); 

            $query = "insert into player(lastname, firstname, picture, birthday, nationality, address, postal, city, email, jersey_number, foot_shoot, shoe_size, jersey_size, short_size, licence_number, mobile_phone, fix_phone, note, team_id, categories_id) VALUES ('".$lastname."','".$firstname."','".$picture."','".$birthday."','".$nationality."','".$address."','".$postal."','".$city."','".$email."','".$jersey_number."','".$foot_shoot."','".$shoe_size."','".$jersey_size."','".$short_size."','".$licence_number."','".$mobile_phone."','".$fix_phone."','".$note."',(".$team."),(".$category."))";

        try {
            $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
            if ($result == true){
                echo 'OK ';
            }else{
                var_dump($result) . var_dump($conn) . var_dump($query);
            }

        } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
        return new Response(" File uploaded",  Response::HTTP_OK, ['content-type' => 'text/plain']);  

    }
    }```
````